Bidirectional serial communication via USB between Raspberry Pi Pico and Raspberry Pi 4B in C/C++
I'm trying to build a simple bidirectional serial communication via USB between my Raspberry Pi Pico and Raspberry Pi 4B in C/C++. In prinicple, my code works well. I can send data from Pico to Linux and vice versa, but my input buffer on the Pico keeps overflowing after a short while. When I look at the messages reveiced by the Pico, there a constantly non-ASCII messages on the input buffer. In addition, the Pico keeps reading its own transmitted messages, thus resulting in a endless loop of sending and receiving e.g. acknoledge messages.
Here is the CMakeLists.text
add_executable(hello_pwm
        hello_pwm.c
        )

# pull in common dependencies and additional pwm hardware support
target_link_libraries(hello_pwm pico_stdlib hardware_pwm)

# create map/bin/hex file etc.
pico_add_extra_outputs(hello_pwm)

# enable usb serial
pico_enable_stdio_usb(hello_pwm 1)
pico_enable_stdio_uart(hello_pwm 0)

# add url via pico_set_program_url
example_auto_set_url(hello_pwm)

and the corresponding C-code
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/pwm.h"
#include "hardware/clocks.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tusb.h>

#define MAXLENGTH 128

const uint PROGRAM_SLEEP = 10;

uint inputLength = 0;

void readUSB() {
  int c;
  uint i=inputLength;
  while (true) {
    c = getchar_timeout_us(0);
    if(c == PICO_ERROR_TIMEOUT) break;
    if(i > MAXLENGTH) {
      printf("overflow\n");
      inputLength=0;
      break;
    }
    inputString[i] = c;
    i++;
  }
  inputLength = i;
}

void processInput() {
  if(inputLength == 0) return;
  // divde into substrings separated by semicolon                                                                                     
  uint last = 0;
  for(uint i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {
    if(inputString[i] == '\n') last = i+1;
    if(inputString[i] == ';') {
      uint length = i-last;
      if(length) {
        char substr[length];
        strncpy(substr, inputString+last, length);
        handleSubstr(substr, length);
      }
      last = i+1;
    }
  }
  if(last > 0) inputLength = 0;
}

int main() {
    stdio_init_all();
    while(!stdio_usb_connected());

    while(true) {
      readUSB();
      processInput();

      sleep_ms(PROGRAM_SLEEP);
    }
}

I also added some debugging to output the received messages, not shown in the basic code above.
On the Linux end, I'm currently only reading the serial interface via cat /dev/ttyUSBx and sending on request via echo "msg" > /dev/ttyUSBx. There is no active communication otherwise.
Tried to play around with program sleep time in the main function in order not to overrun the input buffer. I also increased buffer size but this only buys some additional seconds before it crashes on the Pico.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM

What is inputLength?

inputLength is set by processInput() in order to define which sections of the message have already been processed.

It is never defined or initialized.

Sorry, I forgot to copy that piece of code. It is initialized to zero. I updated the reference accordingly.
